# Receive mouse inputs in inactive region

Tags: c++, qt, qml

I have horizontal slider element which is disabled. I want to enable it when I click on it. As the slider is disabled I am unable to capture mouse events on it.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Your requirement sounds a bit unusual. However, if the slider is disabled the mouse event will be captured probably by something else - I would expect the parent widget. So, you may try to either derive the parent widget and override its mouse event handlers or you use an [event filter](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/eventsandfilters.html#event-filters) for this.

Comment: In normal case, if you dont click slider, it ll not work. What is the purpose of this ?

Comment: The requirement is that on clicking of slider which is in inactive state should go to active state. It's the liberty that the end user is demanding. Otherwise presently the user is supposed to press another button to make slider active.

Answer (score 0):

I must admit that my first suggestion was wrong:

> However, if the slider is disabled the mouse event will be captured probably by something else - I would expect the parent widget.

That expectation was **wrong**.

I found out about this by trying myself in an MCVE.

For my luck, the other option – using an [event filter](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/eventsandfilters.html#event-filters) – does work.

Sample `testQClickDisabled.cc`:

```
// Qt header:
#include <QtWidgets>

void populate(QListWidget &qLst)
{
  for (int i = 1; i <= 20; ++i) {
    qLst.addItem(QString("item %0").arg(i));
  }
}

class EventFilter: public QObject {
  private:
    QListWidget &qLst;
  public:
    EventFilter(QListWidget &qLst): QObject(), qLst(qLst)
    {
      qApp->installEventFilter(this);
    }
    ~EventFilter() { qApp->removeEventFilter(this); }
    EventFilter(const EventFilter&) = delete;
    EventFilter& operator=(const EventFilter&) = delete;

  protected:
    virtual bool eventFilter(QObject *pQObj, QEvent *pQEvent) override;
};

bool EventFilter::eventFilter(QObject *pQObj, QEvent *pQEvent)
{
  if (QScrollBar *const pQScrBar = dynamic_cast<QScrollBar*>(pQObj)) {
    if (pQScrBar == qLst.verticalScrollBar()
      && pQEvent->type() == QEvent::MouseButtonPress) {
      qDebug() << "Vertical scrollbar hit.";
      pQScrBar->setEnabled(true);
    }
  }
  return QObject::eventFilter(pQObj, pQEvent);
}

// main application
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  qDebug() << "Qt Version:" << QT_VERSION_STR;
  QApplication app(argc, argv);
  // setup GUI
  QListWidget qLst;
  qLst.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(Qt::ScrollBarAlwaysOn);
  qLst.verticalScrollBar()->setEnabled(false);
  qLst.resize(200, 200);
  qLst.show();
  populate(qLst);
  EventFilter qEventFilter(qLst);
  // runtime loop
  return app.exec();
}
```

Output:

[image: snapshot of testQClickDisabled.exe (animated)]

Comment: Thanks a lot . I tried to achieve the above requirement by playing with opacity which was completely wrong but fulfilled the visual requirement that was expected.

Answer (score 0):

I would just use a sibling MouseArea, like this:

```
Slider {
    id: slider
    enabled: false
}
MouseArea {
    anchors.fill: slider
    visible: !slider.enabled
    onClicked: slider.enabled = true
}
```